# How can I remove an object from a list using its method?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Here's my unfinished program:

[image: adding class objects with a button]

I made a class for a `Frame()` with input fields and a button.

I then have a `+` button which creates new instances of this class by adding them to an empty list. Objects `.pack()` themselves upon initialization, so they appear in the window.

Edit: added working code you can try:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class JobItem:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.nameLabel = ttk.Label(self.frame, text="Description:")
        self.nameLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.nameEntry = ttk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.nameEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.jobTypeLabel = ttk.Label(self.frame, text="Job type:")
        self.jobTypeLabel.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.selected_job = tk.StringVar()
        self.job_type_cb = ttk.Combobox(self.frame, textvariable=self.selected_job, state='readonly')
        self.job_type_cb['values'] = ['Still', 'Animation', 'Model production']
        self.job_type_cb.current(0)
        self.job_type_cb.grid(column=4, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.x = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="X", command=self.delete_itself)
        self.x.grid(column=5, row=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)

        # v v v This method is what I don't know how to do properly v v v
        def delete_itself():
            pass

job_items = list()

def add_jobItem():
    job_items.insert(len(job_items), JobItem(itemListContainer))


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Estimate generator')
root.geometry('800x500')

headerFrame = tk.Frame(root, height=100)
headerFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

jobNameLabel = ttk.Label(headerFrame, text="Project name: ")
jobNameLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
jobNameEntry = ttk.Entry(headerFrame)
jobNameEntry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.X)

buttonFont = tkFont.Font(weight="bold")
plusButton = tk.Button(headerFrame, text='＋', command=add_jobItem, font=buttonFont, fg='#656565', height=0, width=10)
plusButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=(100,2), pady=2)

# Item List Frame
itemListContainer = tk.Frame(root)
itemListContainer.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I make `X` button on a given instance remove not only the packed elements, but also the object from `job_items` list? How would we know what index does it occupy in the list? Or maybe I should take a different approach?

Comment: To remove values from the list you can remove them by index `del job_items[index]`

Comment: @SharimIqbal but that's the point. We don't know what index they occupy because they're added by a button and we don't track which place they were added at. And when we delete some of them I imagine their indexes shift to fill the gap.

Comment: It is better to post the code on `JobItem` class, especially what function will be executed when the `X` button is clicked.

Comment: @acw1668 the `X` button function is precisely what I'm asking how to do. I don't have any at the moment. The `JobItem` is the most standard object you could think of. It has `Frame()`, `Label()` and `Button()` set as attributes. But it could literally be any other object that's added with the function shown above.

Comment: When you click on the X, you also need to call a function that will `destroy` the frame and then remove the item from the list. Just removing the item from the list will not remove the item from the GUI. You may receive more help if you paste the code for the class and an example that we can run and check

Comment: Apart from acw's answer, I'd change `job_items.insert(..)` to `JobItem(itemListContainer, del_jobItem)`. And I would pass the function onto `delete_itself` via parameter: `command = lambda: self.delete_itself(on_delete)`. Obviously, you also need to change the function to accept this parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to pass a function to `JobItem` which will be executed inside `delete_itself`:

```py
class JobItem:
    def __init__(self, parent, on_delete=None):
        self.on_delete = on_delete
        ...

    def delete_itself(self):
        # destroy the frame
        self.frame.destroy()
        # call self.on_delete if it is not None
        if self.on_delete:
            # pass JobItem itself to self.on_delete
            self.on_delete(self)

job_items = list()

def del_jobItem(item):
    # remove the job item from job_items list
    job_items.remove(item)

def add_jobItem():
    # can use job_items.append(...) instead
    #job_items.insert(len(job_items), JobItem(itemListContainer, del_jobItem))
    job_items.append(JobItem(itemListContainer, del_jobItem))

...
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Although, I don't fully understand what's really happening yet. How does  `.remove(item)` know which item it's deleting? Do objects have some hidden ID? And let me see if I understand correctly: we're passing the function as an argument so the button can call it, because otherwise it wouldn't be able to?

Comment: Every object has an unique ID which can be retrieved using `id()` function. I don't understand what your last question is in your comment.

Comment: I'm basically not sure what are we doing when we put `del_jobItem` as an argument in `JobItem()` and why are we doing it. It's my first time seeing something like that.

Comment: It just passes the reference of `del_jobItem` function to `JobItem` using argument `on_delete` which will be executed inside `self.delete_itself` function.

Comment: Great solution! I voted it up. Now JobItem can do something, which is not in the responsibility of it. This is so good because in JobItem you don't reveal any of the details what del_jobItem actually is. It is just a general function. Nothing more. This could be anything. You don't introduce new dependencies. You don't have extra pointers or extra data.
This solution is called dependency inversion. JobItem should do something outside of its responsiblility. But instead of implementing this in JobItem you implement it outside of JobItem and pass it to JobItem.