# How to add the self-destruct button to a frame in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing an application that generates a dictionary that will later be used to replace keys with values in string, it looks like this:

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Code:
Rule class itself:

```
class Rule(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, number):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text=f"Rule {number}")
        self.number = number
        self.checked = BooleanVar()
        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, variable=self.checked, offvalue=False, onvalue=True)
        self.checkbox.select()
        self.entry_from = Entry(self, width=9)
        self.arrow_point_label = Label(self, text='->', padx=10)
        self.entry_to = Entry(self, width=4)

        # The function in question
        self.remove_button = Button(self, text='X', command=lambda: self.destroy())

        self.checkbox.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entry_from.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.arrow_point_label.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entry_to.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.remove_button.pack(side=LEFT)

    def get(self):
        return {rule: self.entry_to.get() for rule in self.entry_from.get().split(',')}
```

And that's how it's created:

```
def new_rule():
    children.append(Rule(parent, len(children)))
    children[len(children) - 1].pack()
```

```
add_child_button = Button(root, text="+", width=25, command=new_rule)
add_child_button.pack()
```

Generating the result:

```
def result():
    result_window = Toplevel()
    result_window.title("Result dict")
    result_frame = LabelFrame(result_window, text='Result dict', padx=10, pady=10)
    result_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    result_dict = {}
    for each in children:
        result_dict = {**result_dict, **each.get()}
    result_label = Label(result_frame, text=str( result_dict ))
    result_label.pack()
```

So the problem is whenever I call self.destroy function it messes up the result dictionary, since it exists as an element in list but the widget itself is destroyed, hense get() function throws an error. I went as far as writing list child class RuleList and rewriting .append() method, but when the order changes, rules' numbers need to be updated and the problems keep growing as well as the amount of hardcode and it just seems like the core idea is wrong. What's the best approach in this situation?

Comment: I think it is a similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852388/how-can-i-remove-an-object-from-a-list-using-its-method).

Comment: @acw1668 it actually is, thank you